# Android : add score and timer in quiz and reset quiz with new random value

Tags: android

I want to collect score and completed time in different activity based on level . I want to do reset quiz also . every level has 5 question: I want my code should look like attached image. currently i am able to change question for 5 times. but don't know how to update levels and score and timer then generate file which show result  like **level , Score , time**

[image]

```
  public class ArrayAct extends Activity {
        private Button doneBtn;
        private EditText text;
        private TextView textView;
        private String [] mArray;
        private String [] mArray1;
        private int generatedIndex;
        private HashMap<String,String> questionMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.arrayact);

            textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
            doneBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
            text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFld);

            mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Answers);
            mArray1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Questions);
            questionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(doneBtn.getText().equals("Close")){
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        if (mArray[generatedIndex].equals(text.getText().toString())){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if(questionMap.size()==3){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your test is over!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                doneBtn.setText("Close");
                            }else{
                                text.setText("");
                                prepareQuestion();
                            }
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect.Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            prepareQuestion();
        }

        private void prepareQuestion(){
            Random random = new Random();
            do{
                generatedIndex = random.nextInt(mArray1.length);
            }while(questionMap.containsKey(String.valueOf(generatedIndex)));
            questionMap.put(String.valueOf(generatedIndex),"");
            textView.setText(mArray1[generatedIndex]);
        }
    }

        public class ArrayAct extends Activity {
            private Button doneBtn;
            private EditText text;
            private TextView textView;
            private String [] mArray;
            private String [] mArray1;
            private int generatedIndex;
            private HashMap<String,String> questionMap;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.arrayact);

                textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
                doneBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
                text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFld);

                mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Answers);
                mArray1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Questions);
                questionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(doneBtn.getText().equals("Close")){
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            if (mArray[generatedIndex].equals(text.getText().toString())){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                if(questionMap.size()==3){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your test is over!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    doneBtn.setText("Close");
                                }else{
                                    text.setText("");
                                    prepareQuestion();
                                }
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect.Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                prepareQuestion();
            }

            private void prepareQuestion(){
                Random random = new Random();
                do{
                    generatedIndex = random.nextInt(mArray1.length);
                }while(questionMap.containsKey(String.valueOf(generatedIndex)));
                questionMap.put(String.valueOf(generatedIndex),"");
                textView.setText(mArray1[generatedIndex]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CountDownTimer` in android to count down the 1 min. Like this:

```
 new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("time is up!");
     }
  }.start();
```

At the end (in the `finish`) you can do whatever you want. For example change a fragment, or set a new question, or finish the current activity and start a new one.

Comment: please check my edited code . where i can put this code and also for score ,level too.Thanks

Comment: You can add this to the end of the `onCreate`. In the `CountDownTimer`'s `onFinish()` method you can call your `prepareQuestion`.